# Android: White View shown when keyboard shown on Pie and Oreo Version

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, android-9.0-pie

I am facing a strange problem when keyboarad shown in fragment it white overlay view shown above the layout and disapper when keyboard hide

**this picture when keyboard hide**

[image]

**this picture when keyboard shown**

[image]

Comment: Do you use clean project?

Comment: can you post xml code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its not hard problem

Then

In `AndroidManifest.xml` file try to set `windowSoftInputMode` attribute to `adjustNothing`.

Like this :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

I hope that it works.

Comment: i need android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" so i can scroll when keyborad shown